# PDFBox command-line options fail to decrypt a PDF file with valid user password

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using the PDFBox 2.0.8 and trying to use command line options supplied to a jar file for PDF decryption. There are couple of PDF files which result in error saying those can only be decrypted with owner password (okay) however I was able to remove the PDF password with online tool which uses QPDF I guess.

Now my concern is can I just use some same option with PDFBox to decrypt the PDF with out worrying about owner/user password reservations? (I guess YES, because the same password is able to open the PDF with Acrobat as well as save the decyrpted PDF copy by supplying the same password).

My current command line example

```
 java -jar "D:\pdfbox.jar" Decrypt -password xxxxxxxx 
   "D:\uploads\Jjre2pJsC-7KerheiZ8OUt079E7d4dlS.pdf"
```

The exception I am getting:

```
  2018-06-13 - 09:52:30 - error: SaveDecryptedPDF > Failed > Error: Command 
        failed: java -jar "D:\pdfbox.jar" Decrypt -password xxxxxxxx 
        "D:\uploads\Jjre2pJsC-7KerheiZ8OUt079E7d4dlS.pdf"
       Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error: You are only allowed to 
        decrypt a document with the owner password.
        at org.apache.pdfbox.tools.Decrypt.decrypt(Decrypt.java:154)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.tools.Decrypt.main(Decrypt.java:64)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.tools.PDFBox.main(PDFBox.java:52)
```

Can you folks please suggest if I can achieve decryption without the constraint of owner/user password, if I have a valid PDF password and I am able to open the PDF file by manually supplying the password in and PDF reader application.

Comment: sorry I didn't noticed that... I picked those errors from my logs however that is not the cause of problem...thanks for pointing out though I would update with correct log

Answer (score 2):

Obviously both passwords, user and owner, technically allow decryption of the full document. But there is a difference in semantics, someone opening a PDF with the user password is meant to have only limited access to a PDF compared to someone opening the same PDF with the owner password.

Different libraries and tools follow these semantics in different degrees. Some even completely ignore the distinction.

The PDFBox `Decrypt` tool on the other hand explicitly tries to follow those semantics and only allows the owner to decrypt a PDF:

```
AccessPermission ap = document.getCurrentAccessPermission();
if(ap.isOwnerPermission())
{
    document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
    document.save( outfile );
}
else
{
    throw new IOException(
            "Error: You are only allowed to decrypt a document with the owner password." );
}
```

*(`org.apache.pdfbox.tools.Decrypt` method `decrypt`)*

With the tool as is, therefore, you cannot decrypt PDFs merely giving the user password. If you are prepared to change the tool code and recompile the command line tool, though, the necessary change is obvious.